# Auto create sheets within a spreadsheet with formatted columns and cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

What I would like to do is be able to run the script and have it create four new sheets (within the current sheet I'm in) with the following formatting in each:

```
1st row frozen with column headings on Column A, B, C, D, and F.  
A formula in E2 (=D2*100) that would be copied all the way to E30
```

I want to also do some other formatting but if I see the script for the top two I can hopefully learn enough to do the rest on my own. Right now I have started to write a script that uses the `insertSheet` command to create the sheets but I am stuck at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the script that does what you described. The formulas are prepared in a double array `formulas` ahead of time. Then, each new sheet gets one frozen row,  columns headings, and formulas.

```
function setup() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formulas = [];
  for (var i = 2; i <= 30; i++) {
    formulas.push(['=D' + i + '*100']);
  }
  for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) { 
    var sheet = ss.insertSheet('New Sheet '+ i);
    sheet.setFrozenRows(1);
    sheet.getRange("A1:F1").setValues([['Heading 1', 'Heading 2', 'Heading 3', 'Heading 4', '', 'Heading 5']]);
    sheet.getRange("E2:E30").setFormulas(formulas); 
  }
}
```

**However** it's easier to use `arrayformula` command that deals with all multiplications at once: `=arrayformula(D2:D30*100)`. Then the script is shorter:

```
function setup() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) { 
    var sheet = ss.insertSheet('New Sheet '+ i);
    sheet.setFrozenRows(1);
    sheet.getRange("A1:F1").setValues([['Heading 1', 'Heading 2', 'Heading 3', 'Heading 4', '', 'Heading 5']]);
    sheet.getRange("E2").setFormula("=arrayformula(D2:D30*100)");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.  I will tinker with this a little and see if I get stuck again.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Sally, I am stuck again :)  I tried using the arrayformula for Column F but its not working, maybe because the arrayformula will not work with what I am trying to do.  I want Column F to be able to spit out a letter grade  based on Column E, so here is the formula I know works:                           =if(E2 > 89.44, "A", if(E2 > 79.44, "B", if(E2 > 69.44, "C", if(E2 > 59.44, "D", "F")))))"     So what I did was put "=arrayformula( in front of it, but I am getting an error so I am assuming arrayformula doesn't work.

Comment: Sally, here is the only thing I added to your script:         sheet.getRange("F2").setFormula("=arrayformula(if(E2:E30 > 89.44, "A", if(E2:E30 > 79.44, "B", if(E2:E30 > 69.44, "C", if(E2:E30 > 59.44, "D", "F")))))");     I know the arrayformula is correct as I have put it into a cell manually and it worked perfectly.  The error I am getting when placing it into the script is "Missing ) after argument list."  I have counted all my open and close parenthesis and they match.  I'm stumped.